# Regex expression for string conversion in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have requirement to convert below string to target type using regex in Java.

Source String :- **"/india/london/melbourne"**
Target String :- **"India.London.Melbourne"**

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Regards,
Ganesh.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Anything? What problems are you facing? I don't think regex is a good way to go here.

Comment: @Amongalen Regex is fine for this, but you need to use the less known `appendReplacement` tricks from `Matcher`. I'd suggest the author of the question to play around with those.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach and it is working fine.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestLisDedupe {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String sourceString = "/india/london/melbourne";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[/]");
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(sourceString);
        while (m.find()) {
            String replaceFrom = Character.toString(sourceString.charAt(m.start())) + Character.toString(sourceString.charAt(m.start() + 1));
            String replaceTo = Character.toString(sourceString.charAt(m.start())) + Character.toString(sourceString.charAt(m.start() + 1)).toUpperCase();
            sourceString = sourceString.replace(replaceFrom, replaceTo);
            System.out.println("From :" + replaceFrom + " To :" + replaceTo + " ReplacedString :- " + sourceString);
        }
        System.out.println("Final :" + sourceString);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an edit to your question not an answer.

Comment: I have uploaded the entire code. Can this be implemented in any better way ?

Comment: If you want to improve the quality of your answer you might also want to explain it. Code-only answers are discouraged, see [answer], thanks. But you fixed all the previous issues, so I undid my downvote.

Comment: Your code would not work for a couple of edge cases. For Example `//foo`, because it assumes that the very next character is to be upper-cased. Or `foo/` because it assumes that there is a next character to upper-case.

Comment: Using `replace` to replace although you already know the exact location is a waste of time. Replace has to fully iterate the string. You could just do the replacement with simple `substring` concats since you know the positions. Also, building the result string should be done through `StringBuilder` to avoid temporary string objects that just cost time and space.